# How to fetch data from two tables datewise?

Tags: mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to fetch data from two mysql tables and arrange them datewise. The two tables relates to income and expenditure. What I am trying to achieve is first display the data from the date say 15/04/2014 from the income table , then display the data dated 15/04/2014 from the expenditure table and then again loop with the next date and display the data related to 16/04/14 from the income table and then from expenditure table. The present code is looping for as many times the no. of entries in the income table. How to correct this? The code is as following:

```
<?php
  include "connection.php";
?>
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                  <td>Date</td>
                  <td>Particulars</td>
                  <td>Transaction Type</td>
                  <td>Sub Expense</td>
                  <td>Expense</td>
                  <td>Subincome</td>
                  <td>Income</td>
                  <td>Cash in Hand</td>
                  <td>Remarks</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $datequery = mysql_query("select date from income order by date asc") or die (mysql_error());
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($datequery)) 
                {
                $currentdate = $row['date'] ;

                echo $currentdate."<br>";

                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM income WHERE date = '$currentdate' ") or die (mysql_error());
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                            {
                                ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['particulars']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['trntype']; ?></td>
                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                              <td><?php $subincome = $row['subincome']; echo $subincome ;?></td>
                              <td><?php $income =  $row['income']; echo $income ?></td>
                              <td><?php $balance = $balance + $row['subincome'] + $row['income'] - $row['subexpense'] - $row['expense']; ;  echo $balance; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                            }
                                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM expenditure WHERE date = '$currentdate' ") or die (mysql_error());
                                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['particulars']; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['trntype']; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['subexpense']; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['expense']; ?></td>
                                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                          <td><?php $balance = $balance + $row['subincome'] + $row['income'] - $row['subexpense'] - $row['expense'];  echo $balance; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $row['remarks']; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                $date = strtotime($currentdate);
                $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);;
                $currentdate =  date('Y-m-d', $date);

                }
                ?>
              </table>
```

Comment: what is the problem/error that you are getting..?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single query, using the `union all` operator, and sort accordingly. In my query bellow, I've added a dummy column to sort by, so I can ensure that the row from income always comes before the row from expenditure:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT *, 1 AS dummy FROM income
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT *, 2 AS dummy FROM expenditure) t
ORDER BY `date` ASC, dummy ASC
```

Comment: This assumes your income and expenditure tables have the same number of columns, with the same data types, in the same sequence or that you can add dummy columns to make them so.

Comment: tried this as follows, the problem is I have to get the difference between Income and Expenditure whereas here I fail to calculate that. the code I used.

Comment: tried, the problem is I am not able to find the difference between income and expenditur.

$result = mysql_query("select *,1 AS dummy from income UNION ALL select *, 2 AS dummy from expenditure ORDER BY `date` ASC, dummy ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo "<tr><td>" . $row['subexpense'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['expense'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['subincome'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['income'] . "</td>";
$cashinhand = $cashinhand + $row['income'] + $row['income'] - $row['subexpense'] - $row['expense'] ;
echo "<td>" . $cashinhand . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get old-school you can retrieve all your income records sorted ascending date in one query and all your expenditure records in another query, also sorted ascending date.  Maintain indexes into each result set array.  Step forward through each incrementing the array indexes as dates change.  You've done a `merge join` which is what the `union all .. order by` achieves in @Mureinik's answer.  Do it his way, though; it's better.

Comment: tried, the problem is I am not able to find the difference between income and expenditur.

$result = mysql_query("select *,1 AS dummy from income UNION ALL select *, 2 AS dummy from expenditure ORDER BY `date` ASC, dummy ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo "<tr><td>" . $row['subexpense'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['expense'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['subincome'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['income'] . "</td>";
$cashinhand = $cashinhand + $row['income'] + $row['income'] - $row['subexpense'] - $row['expense'] ;
echo "<td>" . $cashinhand . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}